# Copy a field when creating a new version in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I understand that the `Unversioned` and `Shared` checkboxes in `Sitecore` allow us to share a fields value across languages and versions.

I was wondering if there is a setting that will allow me to copy all fields from the default language into the new language when I add a new language version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this by default.  You have several options, but the main ones (IMO) are:

- The no-work approach is that you use the "Translate" view, which lets you see two versions of an item side-by-side so you can transpose one into the other.  The copying process is manual, but at least you don't have to constantly switch versions.
- Another (and by no means the only other) approach is to write an event handler that interacts with the Sitecore API.  Make it respond to a version created event and, in the correct circumstances, copy the values from another version into the new version.

Comment: I like these options. You could also add a button to the toolbar to help you do this. It should be possible to list the fields and allow users to check off which ones to copy.

Comment: @Krisc, You could certainly do that...  It's a little bit more difficult, but not by much.  You could make it into a little wizard with the Sheer UI, if you really wanted to push the boat out.